# HTML convert to PDF not wysiwyg in Django

Tags: django, ckeditor, wysiwyg, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF using xhtml2pdf in django.
I use ckeditor to input and in HTML it's look wysiwyg like this.

[image]

But after i convert to PDF, it looks like this.

[image]

Why in PDF is not same like in HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.
I am wondering if I need a css file like "ckeditor.css" when converting to PDF.

When I converted from html to pdf with pdfkit, it converted well as follows.

```
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'XXX.pdf', options=options,css='ckeditor.css')
```